# WooCommerce, Cart Page – Hide Element when Cart is empty

Tags: php, if-statement, woocommerce, hide, cart

I placed some custom elements on the WooCommerce cart page. When products are within the cart, the page looks great – But when the cart is empty, my custom elements are still there and disturb the empty cart layout. That's why I want to hide those custom elements in that case.

I tried it by adding the following code to my child theme's function:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'henju_empty_cart' );
function henju_empty_cart() {

    if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0 ) {
            echo "<script>
            $('Have-Question-Textblock-Cart-0209').hide()
            </script>";
    }
}
```

Or:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'henju2_empty_cart' );
function henju2_empty_cart() {

    if( is_cart() && WC()->cart->cart_contents_count == 0){
            echo "<script>
            $('Have-Question-Textblock-Cart-0209').css('display','none');
            </script>";
exit;
    }
}
```

But that did not work.

Basically I want to hide the custom elements which have the CSS class ".Have-Question-Textblock-Cart-0209".

Does anybody know how to do that?

Thanks & Best!

Comment: I think you question would results in more answers on -> https://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found a solution that is also working without manual page reload:

```
add_filter( 'body_class','henju_empty_cart' );
function henju_empty_cart( $classes ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    if( is_cart() && WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0 ) {
        $classes[] = 'Empty-Cart-0209';
    }

    return $classes;

}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'henju_empty_cart_ajax' ); 

function henju_empty_cart_ajax() { 
   if ( is_cart()) {
      ?> 
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
         jQuery(function($) {
               if ($num_items == 0) { location.reload (true) };
         });
         exit();
      </script> 
      <?php 
   } 
}
```

and within style.css:

```
.Empty-Cart-0209 .Have-Question-Textblock-Cart-0209 {
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution is not working after all :-/ So still looking for a solution, that is working with the AJAX behavior of the cart page.